# Mysql and MongoDB in SpringBoot

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an application where I have to get all inbox mails and store it locally. Should I use mongoDB to store it or would Mysql be preferred?

**Note**: regular insert and update of mails will be done, so which one is optimal for performance?

How to configure Mysql and mongoDB together in spring boot application? Is there any risk using both together? Since I need to access both at service layer.^